# How to plot a dataframe that contains values spread over a large spectrum of values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following dataframe, resulted from running grid search over several regression models:

[image]

As it can be noticed, there are many values grouped around `0.0009`, but several that are a few orders of magnitude higher (`-1.6`, `-2.3` etc).

I would like to plot these results, but I don't seem to find a way to get a readable plot. I have tried a bar plot, but I get something like:

[image]

How can I make this bar plot more readable? Or what other kind of plot would be more suitable to visualize such data?

Edit: Here is the dataframe, exported as CSV:

```
,a,b,c,d
LinearRegression,0.000858399508896,-4.11609208874e+20,0.000952538859738,0.000952538859733
RandomForestRegressor,-1.62264355718,-2.30218457629,0.0008957696846039999,0.0008990722465239999
ElasticNet,0.000883257900658,0.0008525502791760002,0.000884706195921,0.000929498696126
Lasso,7.92193516085e-05,-1.84086765436e-05,7.92193516085e-05,-1.84086765436e-05
ExtraTreesRegressor,-6.320170496909999,-6.30420308033,,
Ridge,0.0008584791396339999,0.0008601028734780001,,
SGDRegressor,-4.62522968756,,,
```

Comment: How can we know how you wish to represent your data? Take pen and paper and draw the kind of plot you want, we might then help you achieving this using the library of your choice (given the question is tagged accordingly).

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to plot the data in a readable format. I have tried using bar plots, which I thought would make the plots readable. It seems they don't. At least the way I tried. I don't know what approach shall I take, that's my question.

Comment: You cannot draw the street names of Manhattan on a map of the world. Same here. I told you the approach. Take pen and paper and draw the plot you want.

Comment: Can you post the actual dataframe (text) instead of a screenshot?

Comment: @akilat90 I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the graph have a log scale, which is often used for plotting data with a very large range.  This muddies the interpretation slightly, as now each equivalent distance is an equivalent order of magnitude difference.  You can read about log scales here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale

Comment: This sounds very close to what I need. But what happens to the negative values? Ideally, I would like to have them go below 0, for the plot above.